# nlog threw NullReferenceException

Tags: nlog

I build project in Visual Studio for Mac. When project starting, Visual Studio threw NullReferenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

> Stack trace:    at NLog.Common.InternalLogger.GetSettingString
>   (System.String configName, System.String envName) [0x00006] in
>   :0    at
>   NLog.Common.InternalLogger.GetSetting[T] (System.String configName,
>   System.String envName, T defaultValue) [0x00001] in
>   :0    at
>   NLog.Common.InternalLogger..cctor () [0x0000b] in
>   :0
>
> at NLog.LogFactory.GetConfigurationForLogger (System.String name,
>   NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration configuration) [0x0004d] in
>   :0    at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger
>   (NLog.LogFactory+LoggerCacheKey cacheKey) [0x00125] in
>   :0    at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger
>   (System.String name) [0x00012] in :0
>   at NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger () [0x0005f] in
>   :0    at
>   SM.App.Mac.AppDelegate..cctor () [0x00000] in
>   <5a4c63ba6bb041d195b1738f313e25e3>:0
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication:NSApplicationMain (int,string[])  at
>   MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0003d] in
>   :0    at SM.App.Mac.MainClass.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00006] in
>   <5a4c63ba6bb041d195b1738f313e25e3>:0

Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Source: NLog;

Platfrom: .Net 4.5

NLog Version : 4.4.12.

NLog Config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="fatal"      internalLogFile="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}_internal.log">
  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
     <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Turn on Internal Logging to see what is going on - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: If you could reproduce this, please report here https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new